# How to redirect to previous page (page included hash)

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

**Current flow of pages:**

Starts at: http://localhost/pages/manager.php

Then goes to: http://localhost/pages/manager.php#243

Then goes to: http://localhost/pages/generator.php

Then redirects back to: http://localhost/pages/manager.php

**Flow which is needed:**

Starts at: http://localhost/pages/manager.php

Then goes to: http://localhost/pages/manager.php#243

Then goes to: http://localhost/pages/generator.php

Then redirects back to: http://localhost/pages/manager.php#243

I'm trying to redirect from `generator.php` to `manager.php#243`, instead of redirecting to `manager.php`.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can redirect back to previous hashed page?

I've tried:

```
window.history.go(-1*event.state.visited);
```

and

```
window.history.go(-1);
```

However it keeps redirecting back to `manager.php` instead of `manager.php#243`

**Answer**

I've found out that I can actually do it like the following:

```
window.history.go(-1) + "#" + id;
```

Comment: that's because #243 is not a page.. Its just a part inside a page.. history only records pages.. The #243 redirection, please do that through js

Comment: I would expect that works. Changes to the hash are normally included in the history. Going back in history might trigger caches though so you probably don't want that. Can you do `location.href = "manager.php#243";`?

Comment: @Halcyon that worked, but any way of doing it dynamically - so I don't have to statically put it in my code?

Comment: `location.href = "manager.php#" + id;`

Comment: @Halcyon - Cheers :) 
I've also got it working like this - `window.history.go(-1) + "#" + JSON.parse(getURLParameter("data"))["productName"];`